# finding the sum of even numbers in the Fibonacci series

Tags: python, numbers, fibonacci

I came across this solution for this problem and don't understand a couple of lines in it. What does the `n<=1 and 1` part mean in the definition of `fib(n)` and, the bigger one, why is it *not* in the `if not fib(i)%2`? How does that not mean "if the given Fibonacci number is not even, then we add it to our total"?

```
cache = {}

def fib(n):
    cache[n] = cache.get(n, 0) or (n<=1 and 1 
               or fib(n-1)+fib(n-2))
    return cache[n]

i = 0
n = 0 
# we have to pretend the series doesn't go beyond 4 mil
while fib(i) <= (4000000):
    if not fib(i) % 2: 
        n = n + fib(i)
    i = i + 1
print n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break this down a bit:

```
(n <= 1) and 1 or (fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2))
```

This is a way that python programmers used to emulate the conditional ternary operator that is typically available in C but not in Python.  So basically the condition shows that if n is less than equal to 1, return 1, or do `fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)`.

Second question:

This has to do with how python (and other some languages) convert numbers into a boolean condition.  For integers, `0` evaluates to False and every other integers evaluate to True.  In this case, taking the modulo 2 of an even number results in 0, and odd number results in 1, meaning it really checks for whether a number is odd, and there it wants a not odd number, i.e. even number.

Comment: Wow, so `if not fib(i) % 2` translates to `if True`. Mind = blown. Thank you!

Comment: Only if `fib(i)` is divisible by `2`.

Comment: One more thing, is there any benefit in doing `if not fib(i) % 2` instead of `if fib(i) % 2 == 0`?

Comment: It boils down to coding styles. Python programmers generally follow this convention when making a boolean expression, i.e. where expressions of equality are avoided for values that can be casted to `False`.

Answer (score 1):

Fibonacci series start with 1. At that part code checks whether the given value is smaller than or equals to 1 or not.

`1 1` `2 3 5 8 13 ...`

As you can see the Fibonacci function is a partial function:
[image: Image from WikiPedia]